# What does W13/S3 mean in this METAR report?

Tags: metar

Looking at a recent METAR report for [ENQA](https://tgftp.nws.noaa.gov/data/observations/metar/stations/ENQA.TXT), I see `W13/S3` at the end:

```
    282050Z AUTO 36017KT 9999NDV BKN013/// 13/10 Q1026 W13/S3
```

Does anyone know what it means? I couldn't find a description of it online.

Comment: I looked too, even fed it into an automated decoder and couldn't find anything. I want to say it's west thirteen, south three, but I do not know what they are referencing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[From metar-taf.com:](https://metar-taf.com/explanation)

> ### Information about the sea
>
> Weather stations located at sea can report the temperature of the sea water and the height of the waves.
> `W12/S8` means that it is sea water 54ºF [12ºC] with heavy waves. The height of the waves is indicated from 0 (light) to 9 (heavy).

Comment: I saw that page and must've missed it, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: It should be noted that **ENQA** is a [natural gas platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troll_A_platform) off the coast of Norway, where such information is quite important.

Comment: It's amusing to me that `W12` means `54F[12C]` and not `12C[54F]`.

Comment: @J: it may be different elsewhere of course, but in the US our ASOS machines measure the temperature in °F to the degree. They convert this to °C with one decimal place of precision, then round to the nearest °C for the actual METAR/SPECI. And then the pilots take that rounded number and convert back to a now-inaccurate °F figure for the passengers...

Comment: @randomhead Yes, we understand why people convert units - the point was that 12 means 12, **but** can also be interpreted as 54 (following conversion) so it seems to make more sense to say `W12 = 12C[54F]` and not the other way around, ie `W12 = 54F[12C]`.

Comment: @J very true. The webpage itself just says that `W12`=54°F; I had to add the back-conversion myself. As you say, rather amusing on their part.

Answer (score 13):

These values are related to sea state, and originate from a helideck. W13/S3 means:

- Sea surface temperature = 13<sup>± 0.5</sup>°C
- Waves are *slight*, that is *between 0.5m and 1.25m*

METAR from helidecks, like offshore vessels and fixed platforms, are commonly generated by a [helideck monitoring station](http://seawatchpartnership.com/datasheets/RT02%20Helideck%20Monitoring%20System%20(HMS)_LR.pdf), using the *auto METAR* feature. In that case the mention "AUTO" appears in the METAR message, like in your example.

---

This METAR originates from [Troll Alpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troll_A_platform), an offshore plateform in North Sea. Helicopters have limits like the vertical motion of a vessel (heave) or offshore platform where they are landing (the helideck operator may define [operational limits](https://www.helidecks.org/download%20files/HLL%20-%20Part%20C%20-%20p%20r%20h.pdf) too).

- Aviation agencies recommend providing the sea status in weather reports, including METARs.
- Weather agencies have defined how such reporting is done.

[image: Offshore platform helideck]

<sup>Offshore platform helideck, [source](https://en.yna.co.kr/view/AEN20210629004900320)</sup>

**Aviation agencies recommendations**

In EASA [Technical requirements and operational procedures for the provision of meteorological services](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/CRD%202014-07.pdf)

> AMC2 MET.TR.215(a) Forecasts and other information SPECIFIC INFORMATION FOR HELICOPTER OPERATIONS

> (b) Particular mention should be made of the expected surface visibility, [...],  sea  state  and  sea-surface  temperature,  mean  sea-level pressure, and the occurrence and expected occurrence of turbulence and icing.

**Weather agencies**

From [WMO Aerodrome Reports and Forecasts - A Users’ Handbook to the Codes](https://library.wmo.int/doc_num.php?explnum_id=10474)

> Other  information  only  in  accordance  with  regional  air  navigation agreements, including:
>
> - Sea-surface temperature and the state of the sea or significant wave height;
> - State of the runway.

and at section *Sea-surface temperature and the state of the sea or significant wave height*

> Information on sea-surface temperature and the state of the sea or significant wave height shall be given using the following group: (WTsTs/SS’) or (WTsTs/HHsHsHs) where:

> - W is a letter indicator for the temperature of the sea surface;
> - TsTs is the sea-surface temperature coded or decoded as indicated in Part A, section 7 (page 21);
> - SS’ is the state of the sea as indicated in Code table 3700 where S is the letter designator and S’ is the state of the water surface;
> - HHsHsHs is the significant wave height where H is the letter indicator and HsHsHsis the significant wave height in decimetres.

> Example:
>
> - Sea-surface temperature: 18.7 °C
> - State of the sea: Moderate
> - W19/S4

Table 3700 is found in the [WMO Manual on Codes](https://library.wmo.int/doc_num.php?explnum_id=10235):

> [image: WMO Table 3700]